# Fireworks how make symbol button grow at instance level

Tags: button, symbols, fireworks

I have a rectangle with some text on it defined as a button symbol.

My problem when using the button is that the rectangle does NOT resize but keeps its dimensions. And when I resize the button the text font changes too.I have buttons with short text and some with very long texts. Currently the ones with long text the rectangle is not long enough to accommodate the whole text.

**Anybody know how to make a button grow or shrink with text one enters at instance level?**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up duplicating the button symbol and making the rectangle much bigger as I found now way of scaling whatever symbol background scale with the text